# Installing a package to GOPATH in directory with go.mod

Tags: go, go-modules, gopath

I would like to install a package to `GOPATH` using `go get`. This became tricky with go tooling migrated to go mod support.

There is no problem outside of the project directory (=directory with go.mod file). In the project directory, I would expect setting `G0111MODULE` variable should do the job but it doesn't.

```
G0111MODULE=off go get <package name>
```

How I can install a package to `GOPATH` within a directory containing `go.mod` file? 
Thank you.

`go env` output:

```
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/zb/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/zb/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/zb/dev/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/zb/dev/mycopmany/links/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/gf/8xg53y0j2h9d3k5g3_vvvw9m0000gn/T/go-build248955952=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Comment: You could run `go get` from a different directory, but know that go will re-download it if you want to use it in your go modules project (since dependencies are stored at a different path).

Comment: Why do you want to install it in GOPATH if you're using modules? If it's for local development, just clone the repo (which can be done into the old GOPATH of course)

Comment: I don't think it's unrealistic use-case. I've faced it a couple of times already: I am working on something and at the same time I want to install go program that would be accessible as a command-line tool.

Comment: Please share the output after running **go env** command from the directory where go.mod file is there.

Comment: I've added `go env` output.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is named `GO111MODULE` (with a letter `O`), not `G0111MODULE` (with a number `0`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the OP has two distinct needs:

### a. Installing a package to GOPATH in directory with go.mod

(as in the title)

As it is stated in the documentation (source: [Deprecation of 'go get' for installing executables - The Go Programming Language](https://go.dev/doc/go-get-install-deprecation)),

> Starting in Go 1.17, installing executables with `go get` is deprecated. `go install` may be used instead.

Thus, running `go install` (with no arguments, as in [this example](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/compile-install)) from the directory containing the `go.mod` file will move the executable to `$GOPATH/bin` which will allow you to run the executable file from any location — provided `$GOPATH/bin` is part of the `$PATH` environment variable.

### b. “(...) I want to install go program that would be accessible as a command-line tool.”

(as stated in one of the OP's comments)

Now, to address this specific need, you can add `/path/to/project_directory` to `$PATH`

```bash
# either by running
echo "/path/to/project_directory:$PATH" > $PATH

# or by putting the following line in `~/.bashrc` file (i.e. `/home/myuser/.bashrc`)
PATH="/path/to/project_directory:$PATH"
```